# Default Value for MultiInput in Smart Filter Bar

Tags: sapui5

I am fairly new to the whole UI5 and Fiori world and maybe this is a simple problem.

So far I have created a fiori-elements list report using the SAP Web IDE.

[Example Elements Application](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/demoapps/demokit/rta/fiori-elements/test/index.html#masterDetail-display)

In my smart filter bar are shown a few MultiInput fields to filter the data (see: Category field in Example).

For the Category Field I can choose contains and set a value and after I click on OK a Token is placed inside the field and I can Filter the data.

Now I want to prefill this field, so the user does not have to enter it every time.

I tried to add a token programatically by extending the controller and add a new token in `onBeforeRendering`

```
onBeforeRendering: function() {`
    var multiInput = sap.ui.getCore().byId("...");
    multiInput.addToken(new sap.m.Token({text: "myDefaultFilterValue"}));
    // tried text: "*myDefaultFilterValue*" (contains)
}
```

As I would expect the token is visible, but if I click on "Go" the application behaves as if no filter is set.

Do I have to call some update mechanism or somehow use local annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variant Management might be the solution for your problem:
From the Fiori Design Guidelines https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/variant-management/ :

===========

**Intro**

Variants store filter settings which have been defined within the filter bar. The filter settings consist of filter parameters, selection fields and a layout. This control enables the user to load, save, and change variants. In some cases, the table settings are also saved within a variant.

In the context of tables, this control is used to save, manage, and load table settings which include layout, column visibility, sorting, and grouping.

Smart variant management saves both filter settings and table layouts. It creates a page variant that includes all the controls. The button is located within the page header bar, and no secondary management is possible on table level.

**Usage**

Use the variant management control if:
The user needs to save and load different filter settings to find the relevant data.
The user needs to save and load different layouts (for example, a table) to display data in different views.

Use smart variant management if the user needs to save the page, including the filter settings and table layout.

===========

Please see also this blog https://blogs.sap.com/2017/03/23/annotating-and-extending-fiori-element-applications-list-report-part-3/ :

===========

Please note that we have other setting options at our disposal including the control of variant management for our List Report. Variant management allows for storing snapshots of a user’s setting when using your application such as filters within the Smart Filter Bar or visible columns within the Smart Table.

By default, the Smart Filter Bar and Smart Table each have their own variant (See above where both are set to “Standard”). If we use the setting “smartVariantManagement“: true we will now have a unified variant management area for our List Report where variants for both the Smart Filter Bar and Smart Table are saved together.

===========

Comment: ok, I will try that.
Nevertheless i would be interested, how it would be possible to add a token programatically, so that the the SmartFilterBar still works and uses the added token.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution, here the key value will be sent to backend and text value will be displayed to user.

```
 var multiInput = sap.ui.getCore().byId("...");
 var otoken = new sap.m.Token({ 
            key: 'myDefaultFilterValue', 
            text: 'myDefaultFilterValue'
        });
 multiInput.setTokens([otoken]);
```

Hope this helps you.